# When did the Ashkenazi custom to NOT bake matza on Pesach start?

Tags: minhag, history, passover, ashkenazi, matzah

*Historically*, when did the Ashkenazi custom to *not* bake matza on Pesach start? I am specifically interested in when this custom arose, rather than the reasons/opions pro/against.

Comment: I heard that Modern-day descendants of Moranos bake matza on the first day of pesach and eat it on the second day to avoid the watchful inquisitors.

Comment: How do you such a custom exists?

Comment: See, for example, Mishnah Berurah, http://www.sefaria.org/Mishnah_Berurah.458.3?lang=he&layout=lines&sidebarLang=all "והנה רוב ישראל אין נוהגין ליזהר אפילו במצת מצוה ללוש בע"פ"

Answer (score 3):

The [Tur](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacob_ben_Asher) (14<sup>th</sup> century) writes ([OC 458](http://beta.hebrewbooks.org/tursa.aspx?a=oc_x2019)):

(*translation mine*)

> ואני ראיתי בברצלונה מהמדקדקין שהיו אופין כל מה שצריכין למועד מקודם המועד שאם יתערב עמו משהו מחמץ שיתבטל קודם איסורו
>
> And I saw in Barcelona among the particular who would bake all that they need for the Festival before the Festival, so that if a piece of *chametz* were to be mixed into it, it would be nullified before it became forbidden.

The [Taz](http://beta.hebrewbooks.org/tursa.aspx?a=oc_x2218) ([17<sup>th</sup> century](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/David_HaLevi_Segal)) adds that the [Maharshal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solomon_Luria) (16<sup>th</sup> century) also conducted himself like this. [Ateres Zekeinim](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Menahem_Mendel_Auerbach) (17<sup>th</sup> century) also recommends doings this, based on the Tur.

Comment: Barcelona is definitely not in Ashkenaz

Comment: That's not quite true: the tur was written in Spain. Moreover he isn't endorsing this custom or declaring it as existing let alone binding in Ashkenaz

Comment: @DoubleAA Regardless it's a historical source for the custom, even if not *Ashkenazi*.

Comment: Even in Barcelona we see not everyone was doing it. It clearly wasn't even the custom there.

Comment: @DoubleAA The *Magen Avraham* understands the Tur a little different than you: כתב הטור המדקדקים נוהגים לאפות הכל קודם פסח שאם יתערב עמו משהו חמץ יתבטל.

Comment: It could be that since the Tur endorsed it ("והמדקדקים") and published it, Ashkenazim took it upon themselves to follow.

Comment: Was the Maharil following local custom or being extra pious? The fact that someone had to mention it makes it seem like no one else was doing it. (We'd have to check Maharil inside)

Comment: @Ploni No, the Magen Avraham is still agreeing that it's only what Medakdikim do.